# Is $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$-irreducibility in ${\bf P}$?

Tags: factoring

A fast alternative to conventional multiplication is the [carry-less product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-less_product). It works exactly in the same way as the multiplication on the countable set of binary polynomials $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$. We can identify any non-negative integer with a binary polynomial using the integer's binary representation (e.g. $13_{10} = 1101_2$ is identified with $x^3 + x^2 + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$).

In 2004, the seminal paper ["Primes is in ${\bf P}$"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/primality_journal.pdf) appeared.

I was wondering, whether an anologous result such as "$\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$-irreducibility is in ${\bf P}$" holds?

As a bonus, is factorization in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ is "about as hard as" factoring in $\mathbb{N}$? (Not needed for acceptance of answer, but I would be really keen to know this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Factorisation of polynomials over finite fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields) can be solved in probable polynomial time with a randomised algorithm (which is much easier than factorisation of integers). For a fixed ground field such as $\mathbb F_2$, this can be made deterministic. Naturally this allows irreducibility testing in similar time.

If we're just interested in the yes/no irreducibility test, there are some small savings and the algorithm as follows. Note that we can compute $X^{2^k}-X\mod{f(X)}$ with $k$ repeated squarings and a subtraction and so computing $\mathrm{GCD}(X^{2^k}-X,f(X))$ can be done in time polynomial in $k$ and the degree of $f(X)$.

Step 1. We compute  $\mathrm{GCD}(X^{2^d}-X,f(X))$ where $d=\mathrm{deg}f$. If this is not $f(X)$ then $f$ is not irreducible as it either has repeated roots or roots outside $\mathbb F_{2^d}$. If it is $f(X)$ we proceed to step 2.

Step 2. For each prime $p|d$ we let $d'=d/p$ and compute $\mathrm{GCD}(X^{2^{d'}}-X,f(X))$. If this is not 1 then $f(X)$ has a root in the subfield $\mathbb F_{2^{d'}}$ and $f(X)$ is not irreducible.

If step 2 passes for all $p|d$ then all of the roots lie in $\mathbb F_{2^d}$, but not in a subfield so that $f(X)$ is irreducible.